# get dimension of displayable area of android device

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I actually have two code snippets that I need to compare. Which one is more accurate? I am looking for the dimension of the drawable surface of a device.

Code 1:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int result[] = { metrics.heightPixels, metrics.widthPixels };
```

Code 2:

```
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

I need one for using inside a class that extends `View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getSize() was introduced in API level 13. If you want to support API levels before that you should use your first option. In a view you can use it like:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);‌​
int result[] = { metrics.heightPixels, metrics.widthPixels };
```

Otherwise There is no difference in accuracy